# Is the following equality concerning an $L$-function really true?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $\psi$ be a Dirichlet character defined mod $q.$ I have seen the claim that for $s = \sigma +it$ fixed and $\sigma >0,$ that
$$\sum_{n=1}^y \psi(n)n^{-s} = L(\psi,s) + \underline{O}(y^{-\sigma})$$ with the implicit constant depending on $q$ and $s.$

It is easy to see that this is true, using partial summation, when $\sigma >1,$ but I can not seem to show this otherwise. Is the statement really true if $0 < \sigma <1?$ It seems to me that this can not hold then, but I might be wrong and want to double check.

Comment: as long as the character is not the trivial one, the Dirichlet series of the $L$ function converges to it for $\sigma >0$  (conditionally obviously if $0< \sigma \le 1$) because the partial sums (of the character) are bounded by periodicity and the fact that they sum to zero on a full period, so you can continue doing partial summation for $0<\sigma \le 1$ too

Comment: Look up the approximate functional equation.